# Will Face ID work upside down?

Tags: iphone, face-id

I want know more about the new feature Face ID in iPhone X, if user hold it's iPhone X upside down then Face ID will work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Not on iPhone X/XR/XS

> Face ID, as currently implemented (2017), does not work in landscape orientation. (The camera system is optimized for portrait.)

From Rene Ritchie's [iPhone X review](https://www.imore.com/iphone-x-review).

However the new 2018 iPad Pro devices do support Face ID in any orientation.